# Gridview StackPanel Alignment

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-10, win-universal-app

Hi I'm currently developing a UWP App and have come across some design issues. I'm trying to center the items in the GridView but whenever I do I end up with wasted space on the left and right (shown in diagram below) and the scrollbar being towards the center. How would I go by centering the items in the Gridview without having the wasted space on both sides and having the scrollbar on the right most side. The blue outline represents the stackpanel and the greyish is the GridView. Thanks.

[image]

```xml
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FormulaTemplate" x:DataType="data:Formulas">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Width="230" Height="150" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" Stretch="None"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="LightGray">
        <PivotItem Header="Formulas">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,-12,0">
                <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind formula}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FormulaTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 20, 20"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

                </GridView>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>

    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The reason maybe cause by you set the `GridViewItem Margin="0, 0, 20, 20"`. Please try set the PivtItem's `margin="0, 0 ,0 ,0" `, set Grid's `margin="0, 0 ,0 ,0"` and set GridViewItem's `margin="0, 0 ,0 ,20"`.

Comment: Hi Jayden after trying the changes you recommended it resulted in this. http://i.imgur.com/L8QOt1c.png. How do I shift the formulas/stackpanel to the center? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Pivot Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="LightGray">
            <PivotItem Header="Formulas">
                <Grid>
                    <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF983636">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>Two</x:String>
                    <x:String>Three</x:String>
                    <x:String>Four</x:String>
                </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>

        </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The key here is  `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` 
on the GridView.

Comment: HI Tobias, when I used Stretch I end up getting this. http://i.imgur.com/fRus6zw.png How would I move the stackpanel content into the center? The

Comment: Try adding to VerticalAlignment="Center" to the Stackpanel. If not, to the ItemContainerStyle add <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

Comment: Hi dachibox, unfortunately that did not solve the problem. Here is another pic http://i.imgur.com/ODP6NMi.png , making the issue much clear. As you can see there is more space on the right than left. I am trying to center it. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/xXlQ4He.png
The HorizontalAlignment="Center" on the VariableSizedWrapGrid inside the ItemsPanelTemplate inside the Gridview; should do the trick :)